# How do I Interpret KeyEvent.VK_COLON?

Tags: java

On my keyboard, at the moment, the colon (:) and semicolon (;) characters are on the same key. I have to use shift to get the colon. If I want to use Robot to type a colon I can use:

```
    robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT );
    robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON );
    robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON );
    robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT );
```

But KeyEvent also has a constant for VK_COLON = 0x0201. If I try

```
    robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_COLON )
```

I get an "invalid keycode" error.

My question is: where did the 0x0201 come from? How am I supposed to interpret VK_... key codes that don't actually map to keys?

Comment: You can also have a look at [`KeyEvent#getModifiersEx`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiersEx()) which can tell you what "additional" modifiers were active when the event was triggered - this, however, may not help you, as has been already been pointed out, not all key boards are the same

Answer (score 0):

Some Keyboard Layouts have a *direct* colon key and, as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) for `KeyEvent`, the key code depends on that layout:

> - Not all keyboards or systems are capable of generating all virtual key codes. No attempt is made in Java to generate these keys artificially.
> - Virtual key codes do not identify a physical key: they depend on the platform and keyboard layout. For example, the key that generates VK_Q when using a U.S. keyboard layout will generate VK_A when using a French keyboard layout.

The French [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) layout is a perfect example for this question: it has a colon key n place of of the dot key on the QWERTY layout:
[image: AZERTY]

I just added the French AZERTY layout to my system and tested it with the `Robot` class: no error message when *pressing* `VK_COLON`. For science, I also added a `KeyListener` to a `JTextField` and pressing the dot key on my physical keyboard, `event.getKeyCode()` returns `VK_COLON` (as expected) if the layout is set to AZERTY.